# Hyperlink to a file in the current folder regardless of its location on the drive

Tags: hyperlink, ms-office, offline, directory-structure, libreoffice

Putting together a .doc file with a table of content with links to external files. The challenge is: how to make them so that it points to the given file in the current folder regardless of its location on the disk.

Context: I will be sending the set of files to another person, so I can't put the path on my machine, nor on a server since they will be working offline. They will be working on Remarkable device and I want them to be able to use the major overview file with the links to access each of the files, rather than having to browse the folders.

Comment: See [**Save URLs relative to file system**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/optionen/01010200.html?&DbPAR=WRITER). This actually works with the ODT file. Whether it will work the same after saving to the DOC (DOCX) - you have to check for yourself.

Comment: To see how to implement relative paths in Word, check out the solution I've posted at:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html